# python: Is this a wrong way to remove an element from a dict?

Tags: python

I use this way to remove an emelment from a dict:

```
    d["ele"] = data
...
    d["ele"] = None
```

I think by this I can remove the reference on the original element so that the removed data can be freed, no memory leak.

Is it the right way to do this?

Comment: FYI the answers below show the correct way to remove (del), but by setting the dictionary key to None, you will still allow the memory used by the old object to be freed.  You're just not properly removing it from the dict.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You remove an element from a dictionary using `del`:

```
>>> d={}
>>> d['asdf']=3
>>> d['ele']=90
>>> d
{'asdf': 3, 'ele': 90}
>>> d['ele']=None
>>> d
{'asdf': 3, 'ele': None}
>>> del d['ele']
>>> d
{'asdf': 3}
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

That does not remove the key, just the value.

```
del d['ele']
```